# Using Linq to remove duplicate by column values based on a second column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable with two columns "DT" and "ASOF", both dates. There are rows has duplicate values of DT, which I find by doing:

```
      var duplicateGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                                  .GroupBy(row => row.Field<SqlDateTime>("DT"))
                                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

But there is another column, "ASOF" that I want to get rid of one of the duplicate DTs based on the "ASOF" value, basically what ever ASOF date is newest.

I can think of a for loop that will be able to do this by creating an array of the duplicates, finding the newest ASOF, and then removing all others from the DB table with that value. However, I feel like Linq has some ability to be able to do that, possibly with a comparator. But I have some very basic knowledge on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Order by `ASOF` descending, group by `DT`, take the first item from each group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you *really need* to modify the original `DataTable`, you could just create a projection that will give you the records in each `DT` group that has the "newest" `ASOF` value:

```
  var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .OrderBy(row => row.Field<SqlDateTime>("ASOF"))
               .GroupBy(row => row.Field<SqlDateTime>("DT"))
               .Select(rg => rg.First())
               .ToList();
```

Then either clear your original data table and replace it with these rows or create a new `DataTable` based on these rows and swap it with the original.

Another option is to filter the data *before* it's loaded to the data table, but since you didn't specify how that happens I can't offer any guidance there.

Comment: Does `GroupBy` after `OrderBy` guarantee that the order is preserved in the resultant IGrouping? (I honestly don't know the answer). Checking the reference source it appears the current implementation does, but is that a contractual guarantee or just a implementation detail that could change?

Comment: Nevermind [found it in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2): *"The IGrouping<TKey, TElement> objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping<TKey, TElement>. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source."*

Comment: @ScottChamberlain To be fair - I do not believe the `IQueryable` extension is guaranteed to preserve order, but the `IEnumerable` one does.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain In that case you could sort within the `Select` instead of before the `GroupBy`